# Is JSF available as an OSGi (Equinox) bundle?

Tags: jsf, plugins, osgi, bundle, equinox

There is a bundle for JSP/JSTL, which can be deployed on Equinox OSGi Framework and can be used by other bundles then:

`org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jstl_1.0.0.jar`

Is there also a bundle for JSF, so i can use JSF components in my bundles?
I really need to solve this issue, because i have to transform an extisting JSF Web Application to an OSGi Framework suited application.

Help please!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203629/can-you-have-jsf-custom-components-in-different-osgi-bundles
http://groups.google.com/group/spring-osgi/browse_thread/thread/c400b0317a87a27d
http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@myfaces.apache.org/msg39068.html

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of [Mojarra](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.glassfish%7Cjavax.faces%7C2.1.13%7Cjar), the JSF reference implementation, and of [Apache MyFaces](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.apache.myfaces.core%22) are available as OSGi bundles from Maven Central.

There is no need to use repackaged distributions like those from SpringSource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an osgi bundle.

You can pick one from

[springsource.com/repository/app](http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/search?query=jsf&includeLibraries=true&_includeLibraries=on&includeBundles=true&_includeBundles=on&version=)